# In JointJS, how does one position the label of a port relative to the port?

Tags: jointjs

I want to place the label for a port of a JointJS `joint.shapes.basic.Rect` centered right on its respective port, like this example (that I was able to codge from this custom [Model](http://jsfiddle.net/kumilingus/l2f73cbf/)):

[image]

I tried many things, from

```
  new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
    'attrs': {
        'text': {
          'text': 'a'
        },
        '.inPorts text': {
          'ref': 'circle',
          'ref-x': 0.5,
          'x-alignment': 'middle',
          'ref-y': 0.5,
          'y-alignment': 'middle',
          'text-anchor': 'middle'
        }
    })
```

to changing the port object itself to no avail. Are there examples of positioning port labels relative to ports? Preferably for simple shapes in JointJS like Models and Rects?

I don't really want to create a custom shape just to position labels relative to ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JoinJS v1.0 introduced powerfull layouting features for port positions and port labels positions.

```
var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
    position: { x: 425, y: 60 },
    size: { width: 200, height: 100 },
    attrs: {
        text: { text: '', fill: '#6a6c8a' },
        rect: { stroke: '#31d0c6', 'stroke-width': 2 }
    },
    ports: {
        groups: {
            'a': {
                // port position definition
                position: 'top',
                label: {
                    // label layout definition:
                    position: {
                        name: 'manual', args: {
                            y: 5,
                            attrs: { '.': { 'text-anchor': 'middle' } }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            'b': {
                position: 'bottom',
                label: {
                    position: {
                        name: 'bottom', args: { y: -5 }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

rect.addPort({ group: 'a', attrs: { 'text': { text: 'a' } } });
rect.addPort({ group: 'a', attrs: { 'text': { text: 'aaa' } } });
rect.addPort({ group: 'a', attrs: { 'text': { text: 'B' } } });
rect.addPort({ group: 'b', attrs: { 'text': { text: 'B' } } });
rect.addPort({ group: 'b', attrs: { 'text': { text: 'a' } } });
rect.addPort({ group: 'b', attrs: { 'text': { text: 'aaa' } } });
```

The code above results to this:

[image]

for more info visit http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v1.0/joint.html#layout.PortLabel